# CSS - Columns not stacking properly with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a section of columns to stack in two rows of four. When I recreate it here and on codepen the columns stack properly - as I want them but on my site they're stacking in sets of three. There must be a rule I'm missing but I can't see it. This is how it looks on my site -

[image: Section - What we do]

All the margin / width rules are part of the section styling so I'm not sure why it would look like this here. I'm sure this is something really straightforward but I can't seem to spot it. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
#whatwedo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}



*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 90%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80rem;
}

.cols{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  width: calc(25% - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
          perspective: 1000px;
}

.front,
.back{
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  /* size of box */
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.back{
  background: #cedce7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
}

.front:after{
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    /* background shade - was .6 originally */
    opacity: .4;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.container:hover .front,
.container:hover .back{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
}

.back{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
            transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-perspective: inherit;
            perspective: inherit;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container .back{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container .front{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container:hover .back{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container:hover .front{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front .inner p{
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.front .inner p:after{
  content: '';
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #C6D4DF;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: -.75rem;
}

.front .inner span{
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <section id="whatwedo">

  <div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>What we do</h1>
  
  <div class="cols">
   <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="front" style="background-image: url(images/what_we_do2.png)">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Brand Identity</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="front" style="background-image: url(images/what_we_do4.jpg);">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Graphic Design</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="front" style="background-image: url(images/what_we_do7.jpg)">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Editorial Design</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="front" style="background-image: url(images/what_we_do1.jpg)">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Brand Guidelines</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="front" style="background-image: url(images/what_we_do3.jpg)">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Print Management</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="front" style="background-image: url(images/what_we_do6.jpg)">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Signage</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="front" style="background-image: url(images/what_we_do5.jpg)">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Creative Direction</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="front" style="background-image: url(images/what_we_do4.jpg)">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Illustration & Animation</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <div class="inner">
       <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
      
  </section>      
      
  
  
  
</body>
```

Comment: You are not using a `.row`, you specify your own width for `.col-sm-3` ... you can hardly call this using the Bootstrap grind then.

Comment: @CBroe Fair enough, but what's confusing me is that this is the same code here as in my browser but why does it stack correctly on here and in codepen but not in my browser? I haven't used .row in this snippet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use `col` in `row` Class

[**Bootstrap Grid system**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#content)

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"> </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have the correct Bootstrap CDN.
You must be knowing about the Bootstrap Grid System. It divides a given row into 12 equal columns, of which you can use it with the class "col-**-*"..
You need 4 columns in two rows, your code must be like,

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Your code here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Your code here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Your code here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Your code here
    </div>
</div> <!-- end the first row -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Your code here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Your code here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Your code here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Your code here
    </div>
</div> <!-- end the second row -->
</div> <!-- end the container -->
```

Also, do not use a  inside a "col-**-*" tag.
A container, has more width and will mess up with your column. Hence, do remove that...
Hope this works!! :D

```
    <div class="col-sm-3" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
            <div class="front" style="background-image: url(images/what_we_do2.png)">
                <div class="inner">
                    <p>Brand Identity</p>
      <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div class="inner">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```